# Camera Location Search Error: This API key is not authorized to use this service or API

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map place picker plugin from flutter to pick the location/address from map

https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_place_picker_mb

but when I pinpoint the picker, it returns the following error

"flutter: Camera Location Search Error: This API key is not authorized to use this service or API."

I have enabled all the required services

these are the three services that I have enabled

1. Geocoding
2. Places API
3. Maps SDK for android and IOS

Comment: Since this looks like a credential specific issue, I'd suggest that you [file a support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are enabling the services and using the API KEY from the correct project.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72oEm.png)